# positioning in toString() method, Java

Tags: java

This is my question regarding positioning of string in the `toString` method:
i.e. the "Profit Earned" part separately. I know this can be achieved by having a separate `showProfit()` method but the question does not allow it. Everything has to be displayed only using the `toString()` method.

```
public String toString(){
    String str = String.format("%-10s", drinkID);

    str += String.format("%15s%.2f", "Cost Price: $",drinkCostPrice);
    str += String.format("%20s%.2f", "Selling Price: $", drinkSellPrice);
    str += String.format("%18s%d", "Quantity Sold: ", drinkQuantitySold);
    str += String.format("\nProfit Earned for %s:$%.2f", drinkID, computeProfit());
    return str;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
    latte       Cost Price: $2.00    Selling Price: $3.50   Quantity Sold: 30
    Profit Earned for latte:$45.00
    mocca       Cost Price: $2.00    Selling Price: $4.00   Quantity Sold: 30
    Profit Earned for mocca:$60.00
    espresso    Cost Price: $1.00    Selling Price: $3.00   Quantity Sold: 20
    Profit Earned for espresso:$40.00
```

But what I want to output is this:

```
    latte       Cost Price: $2.00    Selling Price: $3.50   Quantity Sold: 30
    mocca       Cost Price: $2.00    Selling Price: $4.00   Quantity Sold: 30
    espresso    Cost Price: $1.00    Selling Price: $3.00   Quantity Sold: 20

    Profit Earned for latte:$45.00
    Profit Earned for mocca:$60.00
    Profit Earned for espresso:$40.00
```

i.e. the "Profit Earned" part separately.

How can this be done without using another function?

Comment: and also, im suppose to display the total profit earned. how do i do that without creating a new method?

Comment: Hi, edit new information/further detail into the question, not the comments. And you don't need to repeat the same information at the bottom in the code as you have at the top in the question. The "i know this can be achieved........" can be removed from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop to run through your `Drink[]` or `<List>Drink` to get:


`latte       Cost Price: $2.00    Selling Price: $3.50   Quantity Sold: 30
mocca       Cost Price: $2.00    Selling Price: $4.00   Quantity Sold: 30
espresso    Cost Price: $1.00    Selling Price: $3.00   Quantity Sold: 20`


Then a second while loop to run through them again to print out the profit earned. You can do all of that in one method.